# How to deploy a WSGI/Python app behind Nginx on Windows?

Tags: windows, nginx, windows-service, wsgi, flask

Coming from the Linux environment, I'll try to be as accurate as possible with Windows concepts I clearly don't master.

**Here's my current situation:**

- I have a functional Windows (10 pro x64) Nginx setup
- It's working well on https, using the computer name as FQDN (static files are reachable through https://computer-name/filenames)
- My Python Flask app works well and can be served standalone or as WSGI thanks to [waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/).

**And here's my problem:**

I can't figure out how *-and if it's even possible-* to bind my WSGI app to the server configuration of Nginx. Considering the well written [Digital Ocean tutorial for Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04), my problem is probably somewhere between steps 5 and 6. Should I apply the same way of thinking and build a Windows service before linking it thanks to a `.sock` link, or is that clearly not the right way?

If that's the right way, I don't know where to learn how to do that and what are the main steps to achieve that. For example, it seems that UNIX sockets are now supported by Windows (but I don't know how) or should I use named pipes (but... I don't know how!).

Hopping that I miss nothing, thanks your help.

## Edit:

Inspired of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778461/nginx-not-serving-static-files-with-waitressdjango-on-windows) configuring a proxy pass works. Is that a solid solution?

Comment: JFYI nginx on windows should NOT be used for production. “high performance and scalability should not be expected”, “… is considered to be a *beta* version”

Comment: May my customer hear you! That's not efficient and the efforts to deploy it are huge. BTW, it's more a proof of concept than a widely deployed app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Waitress Documentation:

> unix_socket
>   Path of Unix socket (string). If a socket path is specified, a Unix domain socket is made instead of the usual inet domain socket.
>
> Not available on Windows.

Instead of running it from a named pipe you can run it in a local port and reverse proxy that port with nginx. So instead of following DigitalOcean article's step 6 you can do this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
}
```

And you can add the `waitress serve` command to Windows scheduled tasks, [see here.](https://superuser.com/a/954969/379646)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to be a really clear & efficient solution. Thanks. The schedule task tip will help too.